# how can I get value of html element attribute in cypress?

Tags: html, angular, attributes, angular8, cypress

I want to get the value of the href attribute of an `</a>` element in cypress, so i can visit this URL inside the test.

this passes inside the test but it does not return the value:

```
  ShareCertificate.getSharableLink().should('have.attr', 'atn-href');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using jQuery:

```
 ShareCertificate.getSharableLink().then(link => {
    const publicLink = Cypress.$(link).attr('atn-href');
    cy.visit(publicLink);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use invoke to get the attribute value:

```
ShareCertificate.getSharableLink().should('have.attr', 'atn-href').invoke('attr', 'atn-href').as('atn-href');
```

Then you call it when needed:

```
cy.get('@atn-href').then(value => {
  cy.visit(value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but the invoke did not work here.
I solved it by using jQuery, even though I don't like the style of the code: ` ShareCertificate.getSharableLink().then(link => {
        const publicLink = Cypress.$(link).attr('atn-href');
        cy.visit(publicLink);
      });`

Comment: Did you also try: `invoke('prop',  'atn-href')`?